# Query with the difference between date frame data frames Pandas

Tags: pandas, date, select, calculated-columns

Starting from two data frames (df1 and df2) I have to build another (df3) one by doing a merge on the 'COD' column and powering a new 'DELTA' column that contains the minimum difference between the date corresponding to the 'COD' and all the second data frames that have the same 'COD'.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'COD': ['cod1', 'cod2', 'cod2', 'cod1', 'cod3', 'cod2'],
'DATE_1': ['30-01-2019', '22-01-2019', '30-08-2019', '22-01-2019', '01-01-2019', '30-01-2019']})


df2 =pd.DataFrame({
'COD': ['cod1', 'cod1', 'cod1', 'cod2', 'cod3', 'cod2', 'cod1'],
'DATE_2': ['24-01-2019', '21-01-2019', '02-08-2019', '03-01-2019', '30-01-2019', '22-01-2019', '30-01-2019']})

df1['DATE_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE_1'])
df2['DATE_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DATE_2'])
```

expected:

```
    COD      DATE_1  DELTA_min
0  cod1  30-01-2019          6
1  cod2  22-01-2019          0
2  cod2  30-08-2019        239
3  cod1  22-01-2019          2
4  cod3  01-01-2019         29
5  cod2  30-01-2019          8
```

Comment: Are numbers correct? If yes, can you explain  first 6 ?

Answer (score 1):

Merge both dataframes on COD (you may need a left join here). Create a new column DELTA and groupby.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'COD': ['cod1', 'cod2', 'cod2', 'cod1', 'cod3', 'cod2'],
'DATE_1': ['30-01-2019', '22-01-2019', '30-08-2019', '22-01-2019', '01-01-2019', '30-01-2019']})


df2 =pd.DataFrame({
'COD': ['cod1', 'cod1', 'cod1', 'cod2', 'cod3', 'cod2', 'cod1'],
'DATE_2': ['24-01-2019', '21-01-2019', '02-08-2019', '03-01-2019', '30-01-2019', '22-01-2019', '30-01-2019']})

df1['DATE_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE_1'])
df2['DATE_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DATE_2'])

df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='COD')
df3['DELTA'] = abs(df3.DATE_1 - df3.DATE_2)
df3.groupby(['COD', 'DATE_1']).DELTA.min()
```

I'm getting the following:

```
COD   DATE_1    
cod1  2019-01-22     1 days
      2019-01-30     0 days
cod2  2019-01-22     0 days
      2019-01-30     8 days
      2019-08-30   182 days
cod3  2019-01-01    29 days
```

Answer (score 1):

First add parameter `dayfirs=True` to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), subtract and convert to [`days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) with [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html), last aggregate `min`:

```
df1['DATE_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE_1'], dayfirst=True)
df2['DATE_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DATE_2'], dayfirst=True)

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['COD'])
df['DELTA_min'] = (df['DATE_2'] - df['DATE_1']).dt.days.abs()

print (df)
     COD     DATE_1     DATE_2  DELTA_min
0   cod1 2019-01-30 2019-01-24          6
1   cod1 2019-01-30 2019-01-21          9
2   cod1 2019-01-30 2019-08-02        184
3   cod1 2019-01-30 2019-01-30          0
4   cod1 2019-01-22 2019-01-24          2
5   cod1 2019-01-22 2019-01-21          1
6   cod1 2019-01-22 2019-08-02        192
7   cod1 2019-01-22 2019-01-30          8
8   cod2 2019-01-22 2019-01-03         19
9   cod2 2019-01-22 2019-01-22          0
10  cod2 2019-08-30 2019-01-03        239
11  cod2 2019-08-30 2019-01-22        220
12  cod2 2019-01-30 2019-01-03         27
13  cod2 2019-01-30 2019-01-22          8
14  cod3 2019-01-01 2019-01-30         29
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(['COD', 'DATE_1'], as_index=False)['DELTA_min'].min()
print (df)
    COD     DATE_1  DELTA_min
0  cod1 2019-01-22          1
1  cod1 2019-01-30          0
2  cod2 2019-01-22          0
3  cod2 2019-01-30          8
4  cod2 2019-08-30        220
5  cod3 2019-01-01         29
```

If final order is important:

```
df1['DATE_1'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE_1'], dayfirst=True)
df2['DATE_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['DATE_2'], dayfirst=True)

df = pd.merge(df1.reset_index(), df2, on=['COD'])
df['DELTA_min'] = (df['DATE_2'] - df['DATE_1']).dt.days.abs()

print (df)
    index   COD     DATE_1     DATE_2  DELTA_min
0       0  cod1 2019-01-30 2019-01-24          6
1       0  cod1 2019-01-30 2019-01-21          9
2       0  cod1 2019-01-30 2019-08-02        184
3       0  cod1 2019-01-30 2019-01-30          0
4       3  cod1 2019-01-22 2019-01-24          2
5       3  cod1 2019-01-22 2019-01-21          1
6       3  cod1 2019-01-22 2019-08-02        192
7       3  cod1 2019-01-22 2019-01-30          8
8       1  cod2 2019-01-22 2019-01-03         19
9       1  cod2 2019-01-22 2019-01-22          0
10      2  cod2 2019-08-30 2019-01-03        239
11      2  cod2 2019-08-30 2019-01-22        220
12      5  cod2 2019-01-30 2019-01-03         27
13      5  cod2 2019-01-30 2019-01-22          8
14      4  cod3 2019-01-01 2019-01-30         29
```

---

```
df = (df.groupby(['index','COD', 'DATE_1'], as_index=False)['DELTA_min'].min()
        .set_index('index')
        .rename_axis(None))
print (df)
    COD     DATE_1  DELTA_min
0  cod1 2019-01-30          0
1  cod2 2019-01-22          0
2  cod2 2019-08-30        220
3  cod1 2019-01-22          1
4  cod3 2019-01-01         29
5  cod2 2019-01-30          8
```